# How to hide the 4th child of a list item

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass

I have a list of items which are rendering in my `react` component and I want to hide the 4th child of the list item. I have the below `html` code

```
    <div class="ExpandableContent-Content MyAccountTabList-ExpandableContentContent">
   <ul>
      <li class="MyAccountTabListItem"><button role="link" class="MyAccountTabListItem-Button">Dashboard</button></li>
      <li class="MyAccountTabListItem"><button role="link" class="MyAccountTabListItem-Button">Address Book</button></li>
      <li class="MyAccountTabListItem"><button role="link" class="MyAccountTabListItem-Button">My Orders</button></li>
      <li class="MyAccountTabListItem"><button role="link" class="MyAccountTabListItem-Button">My Downloadable Products</button></li>
      <li class="MyAccountTabListItem"><button role="link" class="MyAccountTabListItem-Button">My Wishlist</button></li>
      <li class="MyAccountTabListItem"><button role="link" class="MyAccountTabListItem-Button">Newsletter Subscription</button></li>
      <li class="MyAccountTabListItem"><button role="link" class="MyAccountTabListItem-Button">My Recently Viewed Products</button></li>
      <li class="MyAccountTabListItem"><button role="link" class="MyAccountTabListItem-Button">My Save For Later Products</button></li>
      <li class="MyAccountTabListItem"><button role="link" class="MyAccountTabListItem-Button">My Gift Cards</button></li>
      <li class="MyAccountTabListItem"><button role="link" class="MyAccountTabListItem-Button">Logout</button></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I tried to hide the 4th child using the below `sass`

```
    .MyAccountTabList{
    &-ExpandableContentContent{
        ul{
            li.MyAccountTabListItem :nth-child(4){
                display: none !important;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But its not working. How do I solve it?

Comment: Why not just remove the element you want to hide from the list and render it?

Answer (score 1):

Just Remove space between class and `:`

```
li.MyAccountTabListItem:nth-child(4){
   display: none !important;
}
```